# Convert mm:ss string to hh:mm:ss time format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, web-scraping, timedelta

[Screenshot of dataframe I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFz8B.png)

I want to convert the values in df['Chip Time'] column which are string obj to timedelta64.

Have tried this....>  ***df2['Chip Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['Chip Time'])***

BUT GETS Error message ...>  ***ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to add `'0:'` on values matching `'x:x'` only:

```
df2['Chip Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['Chip Time']
                    .str.replace('^(\d+:\d+)$', r'0:\1', regex=True)
                   )
```

Example output:

```
        Chip Time
0 0 days 00:16:48
1 0 days 01:07:51
```

Used input:

```
  Chip Time
0     16:48
1   1:07:51
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `00:` if string has only one `:` by [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Chip Time": ['10:04','1:45:23','23:12']})

s = df2['Chip Time'].mask(df2['Chip Time'].str.count(':').eq(1), '00:' + df2['Chip Time'])
#alternative:
s = np.where(df2['Chip Time'].str.count(':').eq(1), '00:', '') + df2['Chip Time']
print (s)
0    00:10:04
1     1:45:23
2    00:23:12
Name: Chip Time, dtype: object

df2['Chip Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(s)
print (df2)
        Chip Time
0 0 days 00:10:04
1 0 days 01:45:23
2 0 days 00:23:12
```